# Obtain underlying SharePoint HTML

Tags: html, sharepoint

Is there an easy / rapid way to export all the underlying HTML in a SharePoint site?

I know this is easy for a given page but I am looking for a method to take the HTML for all pages.

Is there a solution involving `wget` here?

Comment: Exactly - I need to have access to an archived HTML copy of the site

Comment: This doesn't sound realistic. SharePoint pages are dynamic (aspx), and the resulting html depends on the parameters attached to each page.

Answer (score 0):

You may run WEB crawler with the fixed list of pages that put into it manually (dir > file.txt). This will give you one reincarnation of these pages.